# how to enable all macros of excel using vb.net

Tags: excel, vb.net

Currently, I am working on vb.net that needs to export an excel file with Macros enabled. The Macro is used to disable editing the cells in Excel. For some reason, the options settings on the other computer are not set to Enable all the Macros and the user can edit any cells on the Excel file that could lead to misinformation of the report to be sent on the Factory. This is the link where you can see how to enable all Macro [Enable Macros](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/enable-or-disable-macros-in-office-files-12b036fd-d140-4e74-b45e-16fed1a7e5c6)

Now, My question is: How to enable all macros on the Excel file using the code of vb.net?

Comment: You can't force Excel to run macros. That's a user (and often IT department) option. If you're requiring macros, then the user needs to enable them. If that's not possible, then you shouldn't be using Excel, but should be building your own display form in VB.

Comment: @KenWhite I see. Okay Sir. So maybe, is there a possible way to check the excel file if the Macros are Enabled or not?

Comment: If you want the file to be used only when macros are enabled, then the typical approach is to hide all sheets except for a "please enable macros" sheet, then unhide the sheets on file open (which of course only runs if the user has allowed your code)  https://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office/excel/forcing-your-clients-to-enable-excel-macros/